# How to calculate electric force on valence electron?

Tags: electronic-configuration, atomic-structure, atomic-radius

In order to understand the periodic trends more fully, I wanted to calculate the net force exerted on the electron (with the highest principal quantum number and azimuthal quantum number) of an atom.

I decided to use the following procedure:

- First, I found the [effective nuclear charge of the electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_nuclear_charge) in a table from Wikipedia.
- Then, I found the [calculated atomic radius of the respective atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radii_of_the_elements_(data_page)) (which tells me the distance from the nucleus to the electron) using another table from Wikipedia:
- Lastly, I converted these units into Coulombs/meters and then used Coulomb's law and the charge of an electron to calculate the electric force.

This is the graph that resulted from these calculations.

[image: graph of electric force on valence electron]

For example, for lithium:

- 2s electron - effective nuclear charge: $\pu{1.279 e} \implies \pu{2.05e-19 C}$
- atomic radius: $\pu{167 pm} = \pu{1.67e-10 m}$
- Coulomb's law: $\displaystyle \frac{kq_1q_2}{r^2} = \frac{(\pu{8.99e9})(\pu{2.05e-19})(\pu{-1.602e-19})}{(\pu{1.67e-10})^2}$
- Magnitude of force: $\pu{-1.06e-8 N} \implies \pu{1.06e-8 N}$

Is this a proper way to calculate the electric force exerted on the electron I specified?

If so, how does this graph relate with other atomic trends, like ionization energy and electronegativity?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! On Chemistry mathematical and chemical expressions can be formatted using MathJax (and LaTeX Syntax).  If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details. There were some units missing and I'm not sure I've applied the formatting right. Please check and [edit].

Comment: I am not sure your calculations make sense. I may be wrong. But the force changes constantly if the distance of the electron to the nucleus changes a bit. An electron has a certain energy on a given orbital, that does not change in time. But the attractive force changes as a function of the distance to the nucleus. it is a little like the vibrating pendulum. The driving force is maximum when the extension is maximum, and equal to zero when its speed is maximum. So what you do is obtaining a sort of intermediate value of the attractive force, which does not mean too much.